# Is it okay to use an ACF field to store a password for a protected area of a page?

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, security, password

I was wondering how secure it is to use a simple ACF text field on a page to store a password for a certain area of content on the page? So the user would have to enter in a password in an input field and I would check the password against that ACF field and then load the content if correct (via Ajax). Is that secure to just have that password stored in the database in plain text?

Comment: If the password strength is weak, then no.

Comment: If the password strength was very high, would that be okay then? I mainly just want to make sure someone wouldn't be able to easily find out what the password is.

Comment: Well, I am on hacking sites, I used to make use of tools like Hydra, John the Ripper.  They would crack the password in few seconds to hours based on the difficulty. If it is generated something like this "cE%8UDV9!7apLz^qUN%*kd39Pj" or something it would take years to crack it. By that time you would have even changed your pages and framework :)